# Java System.currentTimeMillis() exhibits different behavior when debugging; almost like two slit experiment

Tags: java, caching, time, system

My code uses the system time to create a delay before an image is drawn. The draw method is repeatedly called in a main loop. Here is the code

```
private long delayToStartDraw = 1000;
private long callToStartDrawingInitialTime = 0;

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch) {
    if (button != null && !shouldHide) {
        boolean shouldDraw = System.currentTimeMillis() - delayToStartDraw > callToStartDrawingInitialTime;
        if(shouldDraw){
            button.draw(batch);
        }
    }
}
```

What is weird is that, if I put a break point on "boolean shouldDraw = ...", it will return true and draw my image every time. However, if I put a breakpoint on the "if(shouldDraw){" line, then it returns false every time.

There is an inconsistency, if I watch the evaluation of my boolean, it always returns true. Only when I do not watch it evaluate in the debugger (which would be the normal situation) does it return false.

I'm guessing maybe the result of the call is cached or something and java is taking a shortcut on the evaluation and assumes its initial value (false) because it thinks it should be the same every call, but does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line where `shouldDraw` is declared then the execution waits until you let it continue, causing more time to pass causing the boolean to be `true`, if you put the breakpoint after it - no time passes until the calculation of `shouldDraw` causing it to be `false`. Btw: where are you setting the value of `callToStartDrawingInitialTime`?

Comment: the callToStartDrawingInitialTime was not supposed to be repeatedly updated, but I accidently left something making a call to update it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes perfect sense. If you put your breakpoint on the line:

```
boolean shouldDraw = System.currentTimeMillis() - delayToStartDraw > callToStartDrawingInitialTime;
```

the debugger breaks *before* that line is executed and in particular *before* the `System.currentTimeMillis()` call occurs. So the clock is "still ticking" so to speak. By the time you step to the next line, the 1000 ms has elapsed and the boolean will be `true`.

On the other hand, if you break at this line:

```
if(shouldDraw){
```

The boolean has already been set (apparently to `false`) and the debugger no longer affects the timing behavior.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a breakpoint, the application will stop immediately prior to that line of code.

If the breakpoint is on the first line, then `System.currentTimeMillis()` will only get called after you tell the program to continue on that line.  If this is a couple of seconds after your breakpoint is hit, it is more likely to make your condition true, as the amount of time you expected actually will have elapsed.